# Why does the websocket connection close automatically after 6 to 8 mins?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, connection

We have an application which internally makes use of chat. The socket object is created using the hostname from the url(https://myorgspace.com/myapp). The code is as follows:

```
function socketConnect(){
    var socketUrl = 'wss://'+location.hostname+'/web-socket';
    socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
    socket.onmessage = function(e){console.log("Socket connected");}
    socket.onclose = function(e){console.log("Web-Socket Connection closed.");}
}
```

The issue is, after 6 to 8 mins, if there is no activity, the web-socket closes automatically. And now the receivers don't receive any messages over the socket.
However, if i connect to the same application over a private IP(EX: https://192.168.1.12/myapp), then socket does not close periodically.
Can anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: You may be having DNS issues so that host names are momentarily unavailable and connection goes down.

Comment: Perhaps the connection is passing through a firewall or router that enforces such a timeout restriction on idle connections.  Do you have the same problem if you actually send data on the connection on a regular basis?  Even if just WebSocket ping/pong messages?